# Adding "Automated Test Type" value under Associated Automation within Test Case in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops, mstest

Does anybody know how to set the "Automated Test Type" value for a Test Case in Azure DevOps? We have UI Tests and Unit Tests, and this would be a really helpful way to distinguish them when querying for test cases.

Note: I am *not* looking for the answer of how to associate automation, this is already done as per screen shot - it's specifically the highlighted field that I am enquiring about. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can edit test cases through a work item query:

[image]

Then update Test Type and save work items:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: That's a useful compromise in case nobody can provide the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update any field value using the REST api methods if you want to. In this case you would need to know the work item ID that you are trying to update, the name of the field you want to update, and the value you want to be applied to that field.

I assume you know the ID of the work item you are trying to update. You can get the field name of the field by calling the GET request in the REST API as follows:

[https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/wit/workitems/{{workItemID}}?$expand=Relations&api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7B%7Borganization%7D%7D/%7B%7Bproject%7D%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7B%7BworkItemID%7D%7D?$expand=Relations&api-version=5.0)

using Postman or similar tool

This query will return all the fields of the specified work item and you can infer the field name from the return. The structure should look something like this

```
"fields": {
    "System.AreaPath": "Test Strategy - Research\\Training",
    "System.TeamProject": "Test Strategy - Research",
    "System.IterationPath": "Test Strategy - Research",
    "System.WorkItemType": "Test Case",
    "System.State": "Design",
    "System.Reason": "New",
```

for custom fields you should see a line that is something like

```
"[custom_name].[field_name]":"[value]"
```

You can update this value with a PATCH to the same REST endpoint but you need to create a data body with the desired field data. The sample post below was captured in Fiddler and will update the priority of a work item:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/itineris/Test%20Strategy%20- 
%20Research/_apis/wit/workitems/335392?api-version=6.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.azure.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic 
OnVhMmg3NWt4MnEyc2hkbW1lamZpdG5sMmlpN3NqZ3c1Y2tqdXVsNGdob3drb3h5MnZsYWE=
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 86
[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority","from":null,"value":"1"}]
```